# Overlap kernel execution and data transfer in C++ AMP

Tags: parallel-processing, c++-amp

While multiple streams can allow simultaneous data transfer and kernel execution in CUDA, it is unclear to me if it is even supported in C++ AMP.

What I would like to do is to read a buffer back from device (I do need the data back on host) while a kernel is filling data into another buffer and then do flip flop with two buffers.

Is this use case supported for C++ AMP?

Comment: There's the `copy_async` function, but the documentation suggests that [you can't copy data when running code on an accelerator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305257.aspx).

Comment: Sorry to be so slow at reacting in here. It does seem to be a limitation of c++ amp. Hopefully one which is lifted, since there are many cases where you would desire to work on one flip flop databuffer while reading the other back.